# Inserting footnotes into titles in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am using org-mode to write LaTeX documents. I want to insert footnotes into titles but it doesn't work. I'm using the builtin footnote syntax like following:

```
#+TITLE: *My title[fn:1]*
...
[fn:1] My footnote.
```

When exported to pdf, the footnote just disappeared. Is it possible to insert footnotes into titles without using raw LaTeX code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so - you have to resort to something like this:

```
#+TITLE: My title\footnote{My footnote.}
```